# How to handle rejection from a client and would you bill for work not used?

Tags: client-relations, designers, business, freelance

Would you bill a client even if they end up not using your work? A client of mine had initially liked and chosen one of my designs but then a friend of their friend offered something different that spoke to them more. The client told me to go ahead and bill them as agreed upon but I just feel a bit guilty billing for a design that isn't being used.

At the same time, I am bummed that my work got replaced by another, and I am curious what professional advice you may have for handling rejection.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you need to add more information here. Did you agree anything in writing or verbally?

Comment: I will rephrase question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can bill the work without creating some drama situation, do it.

Some clients have no idea (=absolute zero) of what they need, so they will first collect ideas from some people, and only then what they want or don't want starts to make sense to them.

If this client went to somebody else to get the job done *after* you proposed something that worked in their mind for a while, it may just be a case of you building that mental path for them.

Which is still called design and should be billed.

Sometimes it works to use an hourly rate, particularly because with hourly fees, they can change their mind 1000 times and you'll still get paid for all of that. I know some designers avoid using an hourly rate like its the devil, but in true fact in works in your favour many times, as larger clients work with teams (or friends in your case), and teams change their mind a lot.

Comment: Thank you kindly, Lucian, for the clear and insightful answer. Greatly appreciated. This also answers my question / dilemma of why my work was being rejected. Hard to not take it personally but you put it so nicely.